# Possible error with series expansion

Tags: series-expansion

I'm expanding the following expression around x=1

```
Series[-((-(16/(x^2 (-2 + x^2))) + 32/(-1 + x^2)^2 - (
  16 x Sqrt[-(-2 + x^2) (-1 + x^2)^2])/(-1 + x^2)^3 + (
  4 (4 x Sqrt[-(-2 + x^2) (-1 + x^2)^2] - (
     4 Sqrt[-(-2 + x^2) (-1 + x^2)^2])/(x (-2 + x^2)) + (
     4 Sqrt[-(-2 + x^2) (-1 + x^2)^2] (2 - y^2))/(
     x (-2 + x^2) (-2 + y^2))))/(-1 + x^2)^3)/(128 \[Pi])),{x,1,2}]
```

and i get the result

```
SeriesData[x, 1, {
 Rational[-1, 8]/Pi, Rational[1, 8]/Pi, Rational[-11, 32]/Pi, 
  Rational[1, 16]/Pi, Rational[-117, 128]/Pi}, -2, 3, 1]
```

while if I use Simplify on the expression first I get

```
Series[-((-1 - 2 x^2 + x^4 + 2 x Sqrt[2 - x^2])/(
 8 \[Pi] x^2 (-2 + x^2) (-1 + x^2)^2)),{x,1,2}]
```

and the result is now different, despite the expression being the same

```
SeriesData[x, 1, {Rational[-1, 8]/Pi}, 2, 3, 1]
```

Can anyone think of an explanation for this? Is this a bug? What result should I consider to be correct?

Thank you

Edit: forgot to add the assumptions

```
$Assumptions = And[x < 1, x > 0];
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your findinds. How do you simplify the expression?

Comment: sorry, added an edit with the assumptions

Comment: OK, I still get the same results for both cases. What version are you using?

Comment: M11.0, which result do you get btw?

Comment: I get your second result, i.e. `SeriesData[x, 1, {Rational[-1, 8]/Pi}, 2, 3, 1]`. I run 12.1.

Comment: alright I'm gonna try to update and see if this issue goes away. Thanks for your help

Comment: The same behavior in version 8.0.  Series doesn't regard the assumptions x<1. It gives the right series for x>1. Plot your function to see a ugly behavior. Do `ser[a_] = 
 Series[f[x, y], {x, a, 2}, Assumptions -> 0 < a < 1] // Normal `  and `Limit[ser[a], a -> 1, Direction -> 1] `  to get the right result for x<1.

Comment: Maple produces $$-{\frac {1}{128\,\pi\, \left( x-1 \right) ^{2}} \left( 12+2\,{\frac {2
\,{y}^{2}-4}{{y}^{2}-2}} \right) }+O \left(  \left( x-1 \right) ^{-1}
 \right)
 $$ under the assumptions $x>0,x<1$ which is simplified to $$ -1/8\,{\frac {1}{\pi\, \left( x-1 \right) ^{2}}}+O \left(  \left( x-1
 \right) ^{-1} \right) 
,$$ assuming $y^2 \neq 2$.

Comment: Ok so I think the problem is with Series in the previous versions of Mathematica. Upgraded to 12.0 and the problem disappeared, it now correctly uses the assumptions given. Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: The problematic piece is the square root, cf. `Series[Sqrt[(2 - x^2)*(-1 + x^2)^2], {x, 1, 2}, 
 Assumptions -> {x > 0, x < 1}]`. Mma 12 returns `-2 (x-1)+(x-1)^2+O((x-1)^3)`. Same for Maple 2019. But Mma 11 and older versions produce an extra overall minus: `2 (x-1)-(x-1)^2+O((x-1)^3)`. If you plot the square root and the expansion produced by e.g. Mma 11, you see that the functions do not agree in the region `0<x<1`.

Answer (score 1):

A comparison between the Mathematica result and the of the question is:

```
Plot[{-(Sqrt[(-1 + x)^2]/(16 \[Pi] (x - 1)^3)) + (-1 + 
    Sqrt[(-1 + x)^2])/(16 \[Pi] (x - 1)^2) + (
   4 - 11 Sqrt[(-1 + x)^2])/(
   64 \[Pi] (x - 1)) + (-11 + 2 Sqrt[(-1 + x)^2])/(
   64 \[Pi]) + ((8 - 101 Sqrt[(-1 + x)^2]) (x - 1))/(
   256 \[Pi]) + ((-133 - 93 Sqrt[(-1 + x)^2]) (x - 1)^2)/(
   256 \[Pi]), -(1/(8 \[Pi] (x - 1)^2)) + 1/(8 \[Pi] (x - 1)) - 11/(
   32 \[Pi]) + (x - 1)/(16 \[Pi]) - (117 (x - 1)^2)/(128 \[Pi])}, {x, 
  0, 1}]
```

[image: Plot of the two functions]

I got the Mathematica result with this version of the input

```
Series[-((-(16/(x^2 (-2 + x^2))) + 
      32/(-1 + x^2)^2 - (16 x Sqrt[-(-2 + x^2) (-1 + x^2)^2])/(-1 + 
          x^2)^3 + (4 (4 x Sqrt[-(-2 + x^2) (-1 + 
                 x^2)^2] - (4 Sqrt[-(-2 + x^2) (-1 + x^2)^2])/(x (-2 +
                 x^2)) + (4 Sqrt[-(-2 + x^2) (-1 + x^2)^2] (2 - 
                y^2))/(x (-2 + x^2) (-2 + y^2))))/(-1 + 
          x^2)^3)/(128 \[Pi])), {x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, 2}]

SeriesData[x, 1, {
 Rational[-1, 16] Pi^(-1) ((-1 + x)^2)^Rational[1, 2], 
  Rational[1, 16] Pi^(-1) (-1 + ((-1 + x)^2)^Rational[1, 2]), 
  Rational[1, 64] Pi^(-1) (4 - 11 ((-1 + x)^2)^Rational[1, 2]), 
  Rational[1, 64] Pi^(-1) (-11 + 2 ((-1 + x)^2)^Rational[1, 2]), 
  Rational[1, 256] Pi^(-1) (8 - 101 ((-1 + x)^2)^Rational[1, 2]), 
  Rational[1, 256]
    Pi^(-1) (-133 - 93 ((-1 + x)^2)^Rational[1, 2])}, -3, 3, 1]
```

Since this is a rational function of `x` and `y` the version with the with the development in `x` and `y` is necessary for a meaningful result. This is special case in which the development into y does not result in a `y` dependent term of the Series. That does not matter, but it matters to forget the `y` development.

The input term looks this:

```
Plot3D[-((-(16/(x^2 (-2 + x^2))) + 
      32/(-1 + x^2)^2 - (16 x Sqrt[-(-2 + x^2) (-1 + x^2)^2])/(-1 + 
          x^2)^3 + (4 (4 x Sqrt[-(-2 + x^2) (-1 + 
                 x^2)^2] - (4 Sqrt[-(-2 + x^2) (-1 + x^2)^2])/(x (-2 +
                 x^2)) + (4 Sqrt[-(-2 + x^2) (-1 + x^2)^2] (2 - 
                y^2))/(x (-2 + x^2) (-2 + y^2))))/(-1 + 
          x^2)^3)/(128 \[Pi])), {x, 0.1, 1}, {y, 0.1, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image: Plot3D of the given function]

Comment: Plot your first plot from `{x, 0, 2} `   to see, this is the right series for x>1. The series for x<1 is `-((-1 + x)^2/(8 \[Pi])) ` . There is no dependance on y, since the continuously liftable singularity at y==Sqrt[2] yields -1.

Comment: You get both arms if you Simplify with x>1 or x<1  `Series[f[x, y] // FullSimplify[#, x > 1] &, {x, 1, 2}, 
  Assumptions -> x > 1] // Normal ` .  Assumptions in Series allone have no effect, seems a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Calling

```
fxy = -((-(16/(x^2 (-2 + x^2))) + 32/(-1 + x^2)^2 - (16 x Sqrt[-(-2 + x^2) (-1 + x^2)^2])/(-1 + x^2)^3 + (4 (4 x Sqrt[-(-2 + x^2) (-1 + x^2)^2] - (4 Sqrt[-(-2 + x^2) (-1 + x^2)^2])/(x (-2 + x^2)) + (4 Sqrt[-(-2 + x^2) (-1 + x^2)^2] (2 - y^2))/(x (-2 + x^2) (-2 + y^2))))/(-1 + x^2)^3)/(128 \[Pi]));
```

we have

```
fx = Factor[fxy]
```

now fx depends only on x, with the variable dependency on y being eliminated.